# Propper .htaccess rewrite mod

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am currently using .htaccess to rewrite my urls from

**example.com/mixtape.php?id=(WHATEVER #)**
...to...
**example.com/m/(WHATEVER #)**

The code i use to accomplish that is below:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^m\/([^/\.]+)/?$ mixtape.php?mixid=$1 [L]
```

The next thing I am trying to achieve, in a clean matter, is to rewrite my

**example.com/edit-mixtape.php?id=(WHATEVER #)**
...to...
**example.com/m/(WHATEVER #)/edit**

---

### **EDIT:** the "WHATEVER #" is the ID of the Mixtape I am editing. Normally i will use "$_GET['id']" to see what mixtape i'm referring to and then i fetch everything related to that number.

IS there anyone out there that would be able to help me successfully write a proper re-write mod?

Comment: Is `WHATEVER #` a number or a random sequence of characters?

Comment: I'm sorry for not clarifying very well. The "WHATEVER #" is the number of the id of the mixtape I am editing (in which i fetch in a MySql fetch). That is the reasoning for the reference to my past code so people answering would know what the number's function was.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment, I would change your original rule as well to allow only for numbers:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^m/(\d+)/edit/?$ edit-mixtape.php?mixid=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^m/(\d+)/?$ mixtape.php?mixid=$1 [L]
```

By the way, I would probably use a general rule and write both urls to the same php file and handle the action in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same rules that you had before but just append an `edit` to the regular expression:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^m\/([^/\.]+)/edit/?$ edit-mixtape.php?mixid=$1 [L]
```

Note that your original rules have the query string `mixid=` while your examples say `id=`.

Comment: Thank you for catching my amateur mistakes. This code worked like a charm. Thank you for all of your help!